# Django (How to prevent users from directly accessing URLs in main_app/urls.py if the User is logged out and user.is_authenticated = FALSE

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

Django

How to prevent users from directly accessing URLS in main_app/urls.py if the user is logged out and user.is_authenticated = FALSE

Please note that I used Class Based Views in views.py. The condition **if request.user.is_authenticated():** is not working. See below:

```
class EmployeeCreate(CreateView):
    model = Employee
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'role']
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if "cancel" in request.POST:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main_app:index'))
            elif "another" in request.POST:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main_app:employee-add'))
            else:
                return super(EmployeeCreate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: "Not working" how? What happens? Did you want this to work when the request is not a POST? And did you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users) on this, including the explanation of [how to do it with class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin)?

Comment: `is_authenticated` is a property, not a method, so you shouldn't call (`is_authenticated()` will throw an exception). But yes, what exactly is "not working"?

Comment: When I tried to logout, it redirected to login page. But when I accessed this link directly, I could still access the add employee page. It means that uses have direct access to urls in urlsl.py without having to log in. http://127.0.0.1:8000/employee-add/

Comment: Yes, because you've only protected the POST, not the GET. See the link I posted on how to do this properly with class-based views.

Answer (score 0):

Class LoginRequiredMixin solved the problem https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin